# Crear una rejilla horizontal en Android Wear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-wear

¿Cómo crear una rejilla de 1 fila y 3 columnas en Android Wear?

También conocida como 2D picker de Android Wear.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo he conseguido, el control a utilizar es el `GridViewPager`.

Obtenido de la respuesta de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788423/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-gridviewpager-on-android-wear) he realizado la siguiente prueba, adaptando código para que funcione, en una sola fila y 3 columnas.

layout `grid_view_pager_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#4400ff00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Adaptador para la rejilla `MyGridViewPagerAdapter()`

```
   private class MyGridViewPagerAdapter extends GridPagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount(int i) {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int row, int col) {
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                    getApplicationContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.grid_view_pager_item, container, false);
            final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(String.format("Page:\n%1$s, %2$s", row, col));
            container.addView(view);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int i, int i1, Object obj) {
            container.removeView((View)obj);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view==obj;
        }
    }
```

Para cargar el adaptador en el `GridViewPager`

```
    final GridViewPager mGridPager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mGridPager.setAdapter(new MyGridViewPagerAdapter());
```